# Compiler allocates same memory for pointers to struct in embedded C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, embedded

I have a structure for which I have created two instances of the structure using pointer to struct and I am expecting them to return two different values based on the input . If I execute this code in Visual Studio Code, I see the int_struct_pt1 and int_struct_pt2 have the same addresses in memory. So when int_struct_pt2 receives it value int_struct_pt1 is overwritten by the same value of int_struct_pt2.

I am working on STM32F4, so I do not want to use the dynamic memory allocation. Is there any other way I can get these data without being overwritten or how do I handle the memory allocation.

```
//int_struct.h
//Declaration in header file
typedef struct {
    int a;
    int b;
} int_struct;

int_struct * func(int a);

//int_app.c
//Pointer to struct in source file 
static int_struct* int_struct_pt1;
static int_struct* int_struct_pt2;
int_struct_pt1 = func(10);
int_struct_pt2 = func(16);

//int_struct.c
static int_struct int_struct_app;
int_struct * func(int a ){
    int_struct_st.a = a;
    int_struct_st.b = 15;
    return &int_struct_st;
}
```

Thanks

Tried creating different variables. Debugged and saw the pointers had the same memory address.
My expectation is to get the best method in C to perform this function without being overwritten.

Comment: Of course it receives the same value, because it is the value returned by `func` and it is the value of your statically allocated `int_struct_st` (btw you really should rethink your naming to make the variables more distinguishable)

Comment: So what do you think is the best way to retain the output of each instance . Do I need to create another variable and copy those from first instance?

Comment: You declared `int_struct_st` as a file-level static variable.  There is exactly one instance of it.  It has only one address.  Did you think that every time any function that references it is called, it magically creates a new copy of it?  It doesn't.  How could it?  If you want multiple instances that persist after the function returns, then use `malloc`.

Comment: It's embedded C . So I am hesitant to use malloc . Also the system I am working on is safety critical

Comment: You can't create new instances dynamically without allocating the memory dynamically. You will need to pre-allocate as many struct instances as needed, and have initialization function taking pointers to these variables and initializing them (if the initialization needed at all..).

Comment: You could have a static array of structs, and an index variable. Then increment the index each time you call the function.

Comment: To create an array I guess we should know how may times the function would be called. I do not have  the information right now .

Comment: You should make a reasonable estimate. If the actual usage exceeds it, then you should throw some kind of error and handle it appropriately.

Comment: You _can_ create a safety critical app (i.e. "realtime safe") _with_ `malloc`. You just have to do _all_ the `malloc` calls _once_ during program initialization.

Comment: For safety-related C you really need to adopt `stdint.h` and in general stay away from signed integers unless you actually need negative numbers for the algorithm.

Comment: @CraigEstey Sorry, but that is misguided - you should absolutely not use malloc in embedded systems, least of all in safety-critical ones. Please note that safety standards like MISRA C and IEC 61508 etc just briefly mention a rationale without giving a deeper insight of why it's such a big mistake. A long list of problems and more detailed explanations can be found here: [Why should I not use dynamic memory allocation in embedded systems?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/286121)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change `func` to be an initialization function:

```
void func(int_struct *st, int a ){
    st->a = a;
    st->b = 15;
}
```

Elsewhere, define a variable for each instance:

```
static int_struct int_struct_1;
static int_struct int_struct_2;
```

If you really must use pointer variables:

```
static int_struct* int_struct_pt1 = &int_struct_1;
static int_struct* int_struct_pt2 = &int_struct_2;
```

Call the function to initialize the `int_struct`:

```
    func(&int_struct_1, 10);
    func(&int_struct_2, 16);
```

or:

```
    func(int_struct_pt1, 10);
    func(int_struct_pt2, 16);
```

Comment: This seems like a great solution for me . Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

```
static int_struct int_struct_st;
```

Has only one instance and if you call your function it will always return the same address of the same object.

You need to create the struct every time this function is called:

Generally (as it is a small MCU medical project), you should implement statically allocated [memory pools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_pool) allocator/deallocator which will not fragment the heap. This is a very trivial example of the simplest implementation:

```
#define MAXINITS 4

static int_struct ist[MAXINITS];
static int taken;

int_struct * func(int a )
{
    if(taken < MAXINITS)
    {
        ist[taken].a = a;
        ist[taken++].b = 15;
        return &ist[taken -1];
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

or with malloc

```
int_struct * func(int a ){
    int_struct *st = malloc(sizeof(*st);
    if(st)
    {
        st -> a = a;
        st -> b = 15;
    }
    return st;
}
```

Comment: The first approach seems like I should know the no of times the function would be called . If I do not have that information do you think malloc is the only way to do it?

Comment: @rishb in medical embedded system it is forbidden as far as I know. `malloc` on small targets tends to "fragment" the heap and fail non deterministic way (Ie you may have enough free memory, but you will be unable to malloc as you will not have enough large block)\

Comment: @rishb malloc is the wrong solution for _any_ embedded system and not just in high integrity ones like med-tech. TL;DR it shouldn't be used because doing so is completely senseless. A long list of reasons can be found here: [Why should I not use dynamic memory allocation in embedded systems?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/286121)

Comment: @Lundin embedded systems != micro conrollers. If you have STM32MP1 Open Linux system malloc is 100% OK.

Comment: @gulpr Well yeah if your definition of an embedded system is a laptop or Android phone, then obviously anything goes. But the OP explicitly mentioned that this is safety-critical using STM32F4, meaning Linux can't be used.

Comment: @Lundin I have now phytec SOM on my desk and write firmware for the IOT device. Linux.

Comment: Yeah so a "PC in disguise". Anyway, it doesn't matter because that's not what the OP is using.

Comment: @Lundin and I wrote in the answer. If you need dynamic allocation - the memory pools are your friends.

Comment: @Lundin indeed a tiny PC :) https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2F6d.jpg